# MySQL where NOT IN except where one

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have threads table for forum. I don't want select threads of hidden forums but except user's own threads. My query like this and hidden forum ids in $hiddenforums variable so i want also select user's own threads;

```
SELECT tid,uid,username
    FROM ".TABLE_PREFIX."threads
    WHERE fid NOT IN ($hiddenforums) /* HERE WHAT I WANT */ EXCEPT WHERE uid = $userownid /* */
    ORDER BY dateline
    DESC LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
WHERE (fid NOT IN ($hiddenforums) OR uid = $userownid)
```

Comment: I want select just own threads but also same time hide threads which opened by other users. Your code not do it same time because of OR statement

Comment: I do some improvements on this and i've fix problem, thanks!